# Redux ConnectedProps is of type never

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am trying to connect a component to my Redux store using the [official documentation guide](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#typing-the-connect-higher-order-component), but the props connected appear to be of type `never`.

Here is my code so far:

Type definitions:

```
export interface CardInterface {
    id: string;
    titulo: string;
    descripcion: string;
    url?: string;
    fecha: Date;
}

export type CardsState = Readonly<{
    cards: CardInterface[];
}>;
```

The actual component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = (state: CardsState) => ({
    cards: state.cards,
});

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, null);

type Props = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

const CardList: React.FC<Props> = ({ cards }) => {
    return (
        <div className="grid-container container">
            {cards.map((card: CardInterface) => (
                <Card
                    title={card.titulo}
                    description={card.descripcion}
                    image={card.url}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default connector(CardList);
```

When I try to iterate over the cards, the linter identifies the `cards` prop as `never`:

[image]

Has anyone else ran into this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Omitting the unused `mapDispatchToProps` argument should fix this Typescript error:

```
const connector = connect(mapStateToProps); //instead of passing null
```

Apparently it's a [known issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/38167)

Comment: Damn, it was actually that easy. Thank you very much!

Comment: Works like charm!